# How to retrieve passphrase for private key?

Tags: ssh, encryption, passphrase

I generated DSA key using ubuntu. Saved the public key on remote server, such that keys are required before connecting ssh.

I have forgot the passphrase for that key. How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it was a reasonably secure password, the answer is probably "not at all". According to the ssh-keygen man page, the private key is encrypted using 128bit AES. Although this algorithm has some weaknesses, the complexity is still high enough to make it reasonably [secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Security). So, assuming a strong password and highly parallel decryption (for instance using GPGPU) having 2<sup>10</sup> threads, each having a very optimistic rate of 2<sup>30</sup> operations per second, after a day of time, you could have run about 2<sup>56</sup> operations. With an effective complexity of around 2<sup>100</sup>, it would take about 3 billion years to break the key...

If it was an insecure password, you might have a chance to break it with [brute force](http://pentestmonkey.net/blog/phrasendrescher) though. It seems the community enhanced edition [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) has a GPGPU module for brute-force attacks on OpenSSH key files (didn't try it, I don't use proprietary drivers).

By thy way, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110152/breaking-aes-encryption-using-decrypted-data), not about retrieving the key, but instead breaking the encryption itself was already asked.

Comment: Considering the complexity of task I managed to add new keys. :P